# GIS scale bar in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, scale, zoom, scale-bar

I want add scale like google 500km until 5m and convert scale to mile  in my map

I use scale setting and load in their  for add GIS scale bar

[image]

But I don't know which standard scale and scale format is like google map

Comment: What Google scale? Edit the question to provide more details.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Please **[edit]** your question to include more info about what you're wanting, including a screenshot of what you see on Google (since you say you want yours to be the same).

Comment: @user91599 Are you wanting a scale slider where you can slide the pointer along a scale and have it zoom in/out accordingly?

Comment: Midavalo yes right and show layer in different zoom acoording to scale bar

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking in the wrong place.  The dialog you are looking at is for setting specific scales for your Scale drop-down.  These are used to tell ArcMap the scale to zoom in/out to.

[image]

It sounds like you are asking how to add a Scale Bar, which is a line marked like a ruler in units proportional to the map's scale, that can be used to measure distances on your map once printed.
This is the one I see on Google Maps:
[image]

To add one in ArcMap you need to switch to the Layout View (from the menu View > Layout), and then Insert > Scale Bar:
[image]

This will present you with a Scale Bar Selector dialog which allows you to select the style of Scale Bar you want for your map, and modify the properties on the scale bar (such as switching units to Miles).  This is done by clicking the Properties button on the right after selecting your desired scale.

[image]

Once you have your Scale Bar set as you want it, click OK to close all the dialogs, and your Scale Bar will be added to your map layout.  You can now move and resize your bar as desired.

[image]

Comment: tanks for your answer but I want to use scale bar with zoom level

Comment: @user91599 Then please add more info to your question as it's not clear.  A screenshot of what you see in Google would be useful.

Comment: I understand how can insert scale bar but I dont know how change number of scale bar with zoom in or zoom out and how can show layer or dont show their in diffrent zoom according to that scale bar